# Wrapper classes and hashcode caching

Tags: java

Wrapper classes like Integer are immutable like String class.

String class cache their hashcode.

Do wrapper classes also cache their hash code like String class?

Comment: Source code is freely available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because it's not necessary.  `String.hashCode()` can take time linear in the length of the `String`, but wrapper classes all have constant-time, fast hash code implementations.

Comment: just for info:Upon seeing source code i found following hashcode implementation: `public int hashCode() {

        return value;
  }` where value is  primitive int value represented by this Integer object.  -- a fast hashcode() implementation

Comment: True for Integer etc.  Just looked at their source code, and (in the version I saw) BigInteger and BigDecimal do not cache their `hashCode` and possibly should.  Avoid them as keys in Maps.

Comment: @user949300:`Avoid them as keys in Maps` --is this statement for Integer(wrapper classes) Or for BigInteger and BigDecimal?

Comment: @aLearner avoid BigInteger and BigDecimal.  Integer is fine.